# Connect R-Pi to different networks with different protocols

Tags: networking, ssh, switches

I am quite new to the world of pi and would like to know if the following is possible. I have a r-pi which runs a php based web interface for monitoring machines on the network.

Network 1:
Linux Machines
SQL Databases
No Internet Access
LAN Connection

Network 2:
Wifi Connection,
Internet, 
Users

What i need to do is have the pi run all my scripts over network 1 (ports 22, 3306, 3307 - Sql & ssh) and then use network 2 to send out mails via php mailer also network 2 is where my users connect to the pi to view the statusses of these machines and run sql queries from the site hosted on the pi.

Is this in anyway possibl;e?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very possible.  All you need to do is statically assign the IP address your LAN connection, and do not give it a default gateway.  If there are other networks that are accessible from that interface, statically route them to the proper router using the `ip route add` command.

Then on your Internet facing connection, be it through DHCP or also statically assigned, give a default gateway.

This will then force any traffic for an unknown network, I.E. mail.google.com, out the Internet interface with a default gateway, and any traffic for the LAN out the LAN interface.

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configuring-static-routes-in-debian-or-red-hat-linux-systems.html for more detailed information and syntax examples.